# É possível deixar o <summary> em Português?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentação, summary

É possível deixar em português as dicas do `<summary>` dos métodos existentes em componentes do .NET ou de terceiros no Visual Studio?

Comment: Escrever o conteúdo em português ou definir a Tag em português?

Comment: Quando vamos utilizar um método pronto no C#, ex: Convert.toint32();
E estamos excrevendo ela, aparece uma dica com os paramentros que devemos passar certo? só que aparece em ingles, gostaria de saber se tem como deixar em portugues.

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta não funciona por aqui, de uma lida logo abaixo do seu post para saber o porque. Quanto a parte de documentação é só baixar uma em português! Vai no MSDN que você encontra!

Comment: @Premiere Qual o problema da pergunta? Ele tem um dúvida que agora está mais clara (depois da explicação que ele deu no comentário), está dentro dos tópicos do site, não é baseada em em opiniões e está longe de ser ampla. Só estou esperando  reabrir para responder.

Comment: Creio que essa dúvida não seja relacionada apenas ao C#, o Java, por exemplo, também usa `<summary>`.

Comment: @AlexandreLima Veja o nosso [tour]. Você pode votar nas respostas úteis e aceitar uma resposta se considerar que ela respondeu o que você queria. Caso isto ainda não tenha acontecido, comente para obter melhores informações.

Answer (score 5):

De fato você já sabe que os *hints* que o Visual Studio mostra são obtidos nas descrições das *tags* `<summary>` contidas na documentação dos métodos. E deve entender que são programadores que provavelmente escrevem isto. Quando você escreve um método e cria um resumo do método provavelmente o faz em português e o VS mostra em português. Um programador nos Estados Unidos provavelmente escreve essas dicas em inglês e é isto que será mostrado pra todos os programadores do mundo.

Isto não surge de um arquivo especial produzido por uma equipe que faz localização dos produtos. Não está em arquivos *resource*, por exemplo. Isto já dá uma dica que embora possível é improvável que tenha alguém fazendo todas essas descrições nos códigos.

Aparecerá outras informações como os nomes dos parâmetros. Você quer que eles sejam traduzidos também? E aí os nomes dos métodos também deveriam ser? Então chegamos no problema do Excel em que as funções foram traduzidas e há incompatibilidade entre arquivos de línguas diferentes, o que é um absurdo. Imagine a bagunça que viraria você lendo algo em português e programando em inglês mesmo.

Nem mesmo a documentação mais completa oficial do .NET é traduzida (a não ser por tradução automática). A Microsoft, assim como quase todo o mundo, considera que um programador precisa saber pelo menos o básico de inglês para conseguir programar decentemente e que nem a documentação ou mesmo a maioria das ferramentas para programação precisam de tradução. Faz pouco tempo que existe Visual Studio em português e não sei se a tradução é completa, ou se deveria existir.

Mesmo que a Microsoft resolva fornecer descrições em português, outros fornecedores não o farão.

É possível conseguir traduções, claro, mas alguém vai ter que providenciar isto. Ou seja, a não ser que exista algo muito bem escondido no VS não é possível obter o que você quer de forma viável.